# Database Connection Close Error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2008

The following function is used by several different methods:

```
Public Shared Function SqlScalar(ByVal sql As String) As Object
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, frmMain.con)

    frmMain.con.Open()
    Dim Scalar As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    frmMain.con.Close()

    Return Scalar
End Function
```

`con` is defined in `frmMain` as follows:

```
Public Shared con As OleDbConnection
...
con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= G:\mypath\mydatabase.accdb")
```

The crash patterns I've unraveled so far are pretty strange, so I'll do my best to describe them.

When it crashes (while debugging) it does so on the `frmMain.con.Close()` line, *after successfully assinging a value* to `Scalar`. VS doesn't give the standard Exception Thrown information, but only gives the following:

[image: Crash message]

Clicking "Debug the progam" just closes the program.

Now, `SqlScalar` is called upon by methods `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`. It runs just fine for methods `A` - `D`, but crashes when called by `E`.

Things I've tried:

- If I comment out any of methods `A` - `D`, then it works just fine with `E`. I thought that maybe it had something to do with just the number of times it had been called, so I put it in a loop that just called `SqlScalar` repeatedly. It didn't crash after 100+ iterations.
- If I run `E` earlier (before `C`, for example), everything runs fine. However, this problem has popped up in different areas for some time and I'd really like to get it ironed out.
- Toggling the project settings "Enable unmanaged code debugging" and "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" didn't help and/or caused other problems.

Edit: Another odd symptom is that sometimes, if I insert a breakpoint somewhere in the script and let it sit for a few minutes after breaking, it crashes with the same error window shown above.

Edit II: I’ve tested the script on several machines (both via VS and the exe), and on some machines it crashes, on some it doesn’t. If it crashes in VS, then the exe does as well, both giving the same error message seen above.  All machines are running Win7 64 bit.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new local connection object each time rather than reusing the same `frmMain.con` connection object?  As long as you are opening and closing the connection each time `SqlScalar` is called, it seems like you aren't really gaining anything by reusing that single connection object anyway.

Comment: I hadn't before, but tried it just now with no luck.

Comment: Does this happen on multiple machines?  Is it always consistent?

Comment: Does it get any errors when you run the program outside of the debugger?

Comment: It is consistent on my machine, but when I tried it on another machine just now, it didn't crash at all. Where can I go with that?

Comment: Yes, it crashes in the same place when I just run the exe.

Comment: When you run the exe out of the debugger, what kind of error does it display?  Surely it's not the same vshost error.  Does the error outside of the debugger also happen only on your machine?

Comment: Running the exe...

On my machine: Identical error message with the exception of replacing "vshost.exe" with "DailyUpdate" (the solution name).

On another machine: no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Dana Wyatt from Hands On Technology Transfer.  Here are some thoughts I have:

1)  I concur that your connection object needs to be LOCAL to the method.  When you reference a public variable in another form, it may be null if the form doesn't exist.

```
Public Shared Function SqlScalar(ByVal sql As String) As Object

    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= G:\mypath\mydatabase.accdb")

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, frmMain.con)

    con.Open()
    Dim Scalar As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    con.Close()

    Return Scalar
End Function
```

2)  Somewhere along VS 2010, it quit throwing exceptions when a connection string is partly wrong.  So you can have an open that doesn't work and not fail until later in the method.  SO MAKE ABSOLUTELY SURE your connection string is 100% right.  It would be best to put it in the  section of a config file and ALWAYS load it from there.

3)  Finally, the buggy behavior on one machine but not another leads me to believe you have a driver issue on one or more machines for the accdb databases.  Make sure you have the latest Office System Drivers, engines, etc downloaded.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Try all of this.  Let us know at HOTT if this works.  I believe you are e-mailing Chris E.  And if it doesn't work, we will try to think of more issues.

Personally, I believe it isn't ONE problem, but a combinaion of several... kinda like three bad wheels on a grocery buggy!!!  : )

-Dana